# Set intellij VM parameters in sbt

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, scalatest

My tests are requiring a lot of memory, and will fail on OOM if I run them plainly.

I'm using intellij to run the tests, and if I set those VM parameters, the tests pass:
[image]

I would like to set those options from the sbt, so that I won't be dependent on intellij configuration, but I just can't seem to make it work

this is what I tried:

```
fork := true

javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx2g", "-XX:MaxPermSize=1g", "-X:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

but this doesn't look to have any affect, and I'm still getting OOM errors.

Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ won't read your sbt config if you are execution the tests with IntelliJ.

Instead add a new `SBT Task`like this: 
[image]

Using a sbt task IntelliJ will use your sbt configuration but you won't be able to see the test results in the IntelliJ test result window.

Comment: it also requires manual intellij configuration,
and it will be the same as running the test with sbt command, so I lose all the advantages intellij has

Comment: There is no way to make IntelliJ configure its own run configurations with your sbt configurations. You have to either choose between executing sbt with your sbt config or execution with IntelliJ and configuring the IntelliJ configuration on its own.